# how to change control height without overflow the other controls

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

i have an access form with 20 text-box parallel to each other , i add data to them using multi-select listboxs , the problem is that they have a large space on my form and i dont want all of them i just need the fields that is not empty so i wanted to reduce some space by showing only fields that is not null and hide all the other fields by putting them closed to each other and made their height equal to zero

```
 If Len(Me.Text0.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
 Me.Text0.Height = 0
 else
 Me.Text0.Height = 100
 End if
```

, so when i update any of these fields its height changes from zero to specific height , but in this case if i have more than one field not empty they overflow each other and i cant see the data of each field , any suggestions ??

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, so I'm adding it as a comment, but have you considered using a Tab control?  In a form where there are more data entry controls than can fit comfortably, using a Tab control can keep things looking neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was a report, I'd say use the `Report.CanShrink` property...

However, on a *form*, you will need to loop through your collapsible `ListBox`es and collapse them as necessary, and then, within the `ListBox`-collapsing loop, loop through all subsequent `ListBox`es and deduct the `Height` of the collapsed listbox from the `Top`, and also deduct the `Height` of the collapsed listbox from the form section's `Height`.

Turning off screen updating (`DoCmd.Echo False`...Code...`DoCmd.Echo True`) while doing all this will probably help.